# Issue with saving OAuth request token using Tweepy as part of Facebook Messenger bot

Tags: python, flask, tweepy, facebook-messenger-bot

I am developing a Facebook messenger bot using Flask and want to utilize the Twitter API for a feature of the bot. I am therefore using Tweepy to simplify the process. However, I am unable to get OAuth working in my program. I believe the source of the issue is that the request token is not saving or being received properly, because when I do auth.get_access_token I get an error - either "OAuth has no object request_token" or "string indices must be integers" depending on how I'm saving the OAuth handler instance. Sometimes, it also fails to get the request_token and doesn't send the link back to the user. I tried to check this by printing out the request token in my oauth_verification() function and it was blank. I've been stuck on this for a few hours, and any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
PAT = '[pat here]'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('[key here]', '[secret here]')
auth_req_token = ''

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def handle_verification():
  print("Handling Verification.")
  if request.args.get('hub.verify_token', '') == '[verification token]':
    print("Verification successful!")
    return request.args.get('hub.challenge', '')
  else:
    print("Verification failed!")
    return 'Error, wrong validation token'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_messages():
  print("Handling Messages")
  payload = request.get_data()
  print(payload)
  for sender, message in messaging_events(payload):
    print("Incoming from %s: %s" % (sender, message))
    parse_message(PAT, sender, message)
  return "ok"

def parse_message(PAT, sender, message):
  original_message = message
  message = str(message.decode('unicode_escape'))
  message = message.replace("?", "")
  if message.isdigit():
    oauth_verification(PAT, sender, original_message.decode("utf-8"))
  else:
    split_msg = message.split(" ")
    print(split_msg)
    try:
      platform = split_msg[split_msg.index("followers") - 1]
      does_location = split_msg.index("does") + 1
      have_location = split_msg.index("have")
      name = split_msg[does_location:have_location]
      name = " ".join(name)
      print("Name: " +name + " Platform: " + platform)
      init_oauth(name, PAT, sender)
    except ValueError:
      reply_error(PAT, sender)

def init_oauth(name, token, recipient):
  try:
    redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
    auth_req_token = auth.request_token
    r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    params={"access_token": token},
    data=json.dumps({
      "recipient": {"id": recipient},
      "message": {"text": "Please login to Twitter, and reply with your verification code " + redirect_url}
    }),
    headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
  except tweepy.TweepError:
      print('Error! Failed to get request token.')

def oauth_verification(token, recipient, verifier):
  auth.request_token = auth_req_token
  try:
    auth.get_access_token(verifier) # issue is here - I am able to get authentication link, but not able to get access token
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    params={"access_token": token},
    data=json.dumps({
      "recipient": {"id": recipient},
      "message": {"text": "Successfully authenticated Twitter!"}
    }),
    headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
  except tweepy.TweepError:
      print('Error! Failed to get access token.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `auth_req_token` is a global variable, you need to use the `global` keyword to change its value in `init_oauth`:

```
def init_oauth(name, token, recipient):
    global auth_req_token
    try:
        redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
        auth_req_token = auth.request_token
        # ...
```

Comment: As an aside: if you can, avoid using global variables. Maintaining global state can get very messy very quickly.

Comment: @tekknolagi I'm still struggling with a name not defined issue for the global variable, but that seems much easier to debug - I understand it's not ideal to be using them at all, though.

Comment: If you pass it around a couple of your functions, you'll save a lot of heartache. Globals, particularly in Python, are difficult.